# Indicating a non-value following an array

Tags: php

At the end of the code I posted below is a simple PHP switch that includes a file only if there's a value for $Group. However, it doesn't work, apparently because $Group is incorporated into an array. It doesn't work if I replace $Group with $Group1 or $Group1[], either.

So my question is simple: How can I modify my switch so it includes a file only if there's something to display in that file?

```
while ($row = $Groups->fetch())
{
$Group = $row['Title'];
$URL = $row['URL'];
$Link = $row['Links'];

$Group1[] = '<li role="presentation"><a href="/life/'.$URL.'"  title="'.$Group.'">'.$Group.'</a></li>';
}

switch($Group)
{
 case '':
 // DO NOTHING
 break;
 default:
 require($BaseINC."/2b/inc/file.php");
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the variable before, so you can check its value. Also, the switch can be a much simpler if:

```
$Group1 = array();
while ($row = $Groups->fetch())
{
  $Group = $row['Title'];
  $URL = $row['URL'];
  $Link = $row['Links'];

  $Group1[] = '<li role="presentation"><a href="/life/'.$URL.'"  title="'.$Group.'">'.$Group.'</a></li>';
}

if (count($Group1) > 0) {
  require($BaseINC."/2b/inc/file.php");
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still includes the file even if there's an empty array. I'll play with it a little more; maybe I'm doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Although I mentioned it in the text, I forgot to add the line `$Group1 = array();` at the start of the code. Maybe that was the issue.

Comment: I'm confused - am I supposed to insert the code $Group1 = array(); If so, where? In the meantime, I fixed it by replacing > 0 with > 1. I have no idea why I need 1 when there's nothing in the database, but it works. ;)

Comment: As the first line in the code that I posted. It's just to initialize `$Group1` to an empty array, so even if the while loop doesn't iterate at all, `$Group1` is still a valid (and empty) array after the loop.